# Реализация сайта на нескольких языках

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Создаю рервис сайт по ремонту домов на двух языках (Азербайджанский и Русский). В программировании разбираюсь слабо. Нашел устраювающий меня скрипт и перевел весь сайт. И было все хорошо, пока не начал создавать страницы и статьи, ведь они же также должны переводится, но скрит перевода работает на массивах, долго не думал, понял - нужно создавать таблицы на дву язаках, это несложно! Страница id=1 будет с русским текстом, а страница с id=2 на азерб. языке. НО! Скрипт перевода при выборе определенного языка не трогает таблицы. Мда уж, тут уже без помощи профи не обойтись. Может, как-то сделать id=1_rus или rus=1 aze=1. Прошу вашей помощи.
CMS не использую, пишу сам.
Вот скрипт перевода:

```
$LangArray = array("Russkiy", "Azerbaycan");
    $DefaultLang = "Russkiy";
    if(@$_SESSION['NowLang']) {
       if(!in_array($_SESSION['NowLang'], $LangArray)) {
       $_SESSION['NowLang'] = $DefaultLang;
    }
    }
    else {$_SESSION['NowLang'] = $DefaultLang;}
    $language = addslashes($_GET['language']);
    if($language) {if(!in_array($language, $LangArray)) {
        $_SESSION['NowLang'] = $DefaultLang;}
        else {$_SESSION['NowLang'] = $language;}
    }
    $CurentLang = addslashes($_SESSION['NowLang']);
    include_once (ROOT.'/languages/'.$CurentLang.'.php');
```

Comment: Покажите код, где получаете содержимое из таблиц.

Comment: Если вам не сложно, покажите, пожалуйста, пример запроса, приведенный вами в php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов множество:

1. Одна таблица для контента (страниц), для каждого языка дублируется текстовая ячейка (title_rus, title_aze, text_rus, text_aze и т. д.). В url'ы добавляется GET переменная lang, тогда адрес будет примерно такого вида `http://example.com/index.php?id=1&lang=rus`. Перед тем как послать запрос к БД на получение данных страницы, проверяется наличие и значение `GET['lang']`, и в зависимости от её значения выбираются те или иные ячейки. Также для упрощения можно сделать язык по умолчанию, то бишь при отсутствии переменной `GET['lang']` выбирать определённый язык.
2. Две таблицы. Одна с id страниц, вторая со значениями для языков. Структура второй таблицы - pageID, lang, title, text и т. д. В данном случае в запрос встраивается `where pageID = GET[id] and lang = GET[lang]`. Этот вариант лучше для случаев, если языков будет много.

### Пример

#### Структура таблиц

- table page:

  - id (auto_increment),
  - date_added (дата создания),
  - date_update (дата последнего редактирования),
  - active(статус доступности, бывают случаи чтобы страница оставалась в БД но не была видна с лицевой части)

  Отдельная таблица нужна для удобства ведения id страниц, чтобы при добавлении каждой новой страницы не вычислять последний id в таблице page_lang. При создании новой страницы отправляем запрос:

  ```
  insert into page set active = 1
  ```

  после выполнения получаем id нашей страницы через mysql_insert_id

  *пример заполнения:*

  ```
  |id|date_added|last_update|active|
  |1 |01.12.2013|31.03.2014 |  1   |
  |2 |05.01.2014|25.04.2014 |  1   |
  ```
- table lang:

  - id (auto_increment),
  - lang_name (varchar)

  *пример заполнения:*

  ```
  |id|lang_name|
  |1 |    rus  |
  |2 |    aze  |
  ```
- table page_lang:

  - page_id (связан с page.id),
  - lang_id (связан с lang.id),
  - title,
  - meta_d,
  - meta_k,
  - text (в зависимости от lang_id содержит текстовые данные на указанном языке).

  *пример заполнения:*

  ```
  |page_id|lang_id|  title   |   meta_d   |   meta_k   |        text       |
  |   1   |   1   |  Главная |  Главная   |  Главная   |   основной текст  |
  |   1   |   2   |Ana səhifə| Ana səhifə | Ana səhifə |     əsas mətn     |
  |   2   |   1   |   О нас  |    О нас   |   О нас    |   основной текст  |
  |   2   |   2   |Haqqımızda| Haqqımızda | Haqqımızda |Bizim haqqında mətn|
  ```

#### Логика

При первичном заходе на сайт устанавливаем `$lang` по умолчанию. При изменении языка пользователем проверяем наличие `$_GET[lang]` и её значение. При отсутствии `$_GET[lang]` берём значение по умолчанию. При несоответствии значения (к примеру есть rus, aze, eng а к нам приходит `&lang=blabla`) отправляем на *404.html*. При соответствии значения и наличии `$_GET[id]` составляем запрос к БД:

```
select
    pl.* 
 from 
    page_lang as pl 
    inner join lang on (pl.lang_id = lang.id)
 where
    pl.page_id = $id and pl.active = 1 and lang.lang_name = $lang
```

настоятельно рекомендую перед использованием переменных в запросе проверять их.

Comment: большое вам спасибо! Буду пробывать

Comment: @Shahin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Можете как нибуть на примере кодом показать второй вариант, а если не сложно  и первый

Comment: Куда писать select

        pl.* 
     from 
        page_lang as pl 
        inner join lang on (pl.lang_id = lang.id)
     where
        pl.id = $id and lang.lang_name = $lang

И что это? В php таких запросов не видел.

Comment: Как Вы выбираете данные из БД?

Comment: Так это я понял, как сделать, чтобы при выборе языка скриптом (который я написал выше) выводилась нужная база, помимо перевода константами.

Answer (score 1):

Как насчёт того, чтобы добавить в таблицу ещё один столбец для содержимого? Первый столбец -- контент на русском, второй -- контент на азербайджанском.

Мало информации. Приведите названия и версии используемых CMS и плагинов, а также куски кода, где используете таблицы, массивы.